# Aside from cockroaches and other insects, which species (of all kinds) are 'immune' to ionizing radiation?

Tags: zoology, botany, bacteriology, mycology, radiation

I have just been reading [this excellent question and answer about cockroaches ability to withstand ionizing radiation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-cockroaches-resist-the-effects-of-ionizing-radiation).  My question is an extension of that question: aside from insects, which other animals (if any) have an increased defence against ionizing radiation?

Are there species of plants, fungi, and bacteria also "immune"?

Comment: Deinococcus radiodurans (bacteria), tardigrades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Paul Stamets](http://hopedance.org/other-news/1971-myco-remediation-of-the-japanese-landscape-after-radioactive-fallout-), *Gomphidius glutinosus* is especially well suited to collecting Cesium-137:

> *G. glutinosus* has been reported to absorb – via the mycelium – and
>   concentrate radioactive Cesium 137 more than 10,000-fold over ambient
>   background levels.

That article and Stamets' book *Mycelium Running* have more details on other species.